# ( Highcharts ) How to make dataLabels disappear if there is, a higher column?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a chart which has attribute column.grouping set to false,
and I would like to show data labels only on highest columns.
[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/7zc5peyf/)

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true
}
```

I have tried to find solution for couple hours now, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you want to show data label for highest point or want to show stacklabel at highest point ? Datalable is inside column while stacklabel remains on the top of column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be the easiest to use `point.dataLabels.enabled` option. Just preprocess data before rendering the chart, to determine which points should display values, see: http://jsfiddle.net/9f1maj3x/

And code:

```
function enableLabels(d_1, d_2) {
    // compare two data series and enable dataLabel for a higher column:

    $.each(d_1, function (i, point) {
        if (point > d_2[i]) {
            d_1[i] = {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                y: d_1[i]
            }
        } else {
            d_2[i] = {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                y: d_2[i]
            }
        }
    });

    return [d_1, d_2];
}
```

Data example:

```
var data = [
    [150, 73, 20],
    [140, 90, 40],
    [103.6, 178.8, 198.5],
    [203.6, 198.8, 208.5]
];

var leftColumns = enableLabels(data[0], data[1]),
    rightColumns = enableLabels(data[2], data[3]);
```

And example in Highcharts:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Employees',
        color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
        data: leftColumns[0],
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: -0.2
    }, {
        name: 'Employees Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
        data: leftColumns[1],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: -0.2
    }, {
        name: 'Profit',
        color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
        data: rightColumns[0],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueSuffix: ' M'
        },
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: 0.2,
        yAxis: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Profit Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
        data: rightColumns[1],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueSuffix: ' M'
        },
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: 0.2,
        yAxis: 1
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as, I have written under Andrew post, I have already had that solution, what I am looking for is to show value of the highest **visible** column, so it would have to change dynamically.

Comment: But you need to display only one label, for the highest visible column, or for the highest column with the same placement, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7zc5peyf/5/ ?

Comment: For the same column with the same placement, I had to delete previous comment as it is not correct solution, in your version, if you will change values for profit, it doesn't work correctly anymore. example: http://jsfiddle.net/7zc5peyf/7/

Comment: Right, see updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7zc5peyf/8/ - I was hoping to avoid if-else statements ;)

Comment: It is much better now, but still not correct, as if you will hide all columns, data labels are still visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a formatter for the dataLabel that checks if it's the highest for that yAxis, here's the API documentation:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter

After comments: You can take the data out of the chart object and use a formatter to pick the largest one, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zc5peyf/1/

```
var em = [150, 73, 20];
var eo = [140, 90, 40];
```

data label code:

```
data: em,
dataLabels:{
  enabled: true,
  formatter: function(){
    if(this.y > eo[this.point.index]){
      return this.y;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but from api reference available data is only from current object, so how can I compare data from different series?

Comment: Make the chart into an object, e.g. var chart = new Highcharts.chart({ ... });

Comment: actually, I'm not so sure the chart object has been created at the point this is run, you can do it by taking the data outside the chart, here's a (not the greatest but it works) solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7zc5peyf/1/

Comment: I had already the same solution as you have, but the problem is when you click legend and hide column with the highest value, the value disappear completely and I need value on the highest **visible** column

Comment: that's more of a challenge as I don't think you can change these after it's drawn (it's also different to the question asked, perhaps rephrase your question?) Worth having a look at the hide and show events on series: http://jsfiddle.net/7zc5peyf/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
chart.yAxis[0].max;
```

or

```
this.dataMax
```

to get maximum value. to compare , in formatter function compare both and retrun larger one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
$(function () {
var something = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Seattle HQ',
            'San Francisco',
            'Tokyo']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Employees'
        }
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Profit (millions)'
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    legend: {
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false,
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: {
            events: {
                hide: function () {
                    console.log(this);
                },
                show: function () {
                    console.log(this);
                },
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < something.series.length; i++) {
                        if (something.series[i].name === this.name) {
                            something.series[i].visible = !this.visible;
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(this.name);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Employees',
        color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
        visible: true,
        data: [150, 73, 20],
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: -0.2,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var index = something.xAxis.categories.indexOf(this.x);
                if ((this.y > something.series[1].data[index]) || !something.series[1].visible) {
                    console.log(something.series.visible);
                    return this.y + '*';
                }
                return '';
            }
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Employees Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
        visible: true,
        data: [140, 90, 40],
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: -0.2,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var index = something.xAxis.categories.indexOf(this.x);
                if ((this.y > something.series[0].data[index]) || !something.series[0].visible) {
                    console.log(something.series.visible);
                    return this.y + '*';
                }
                return '';
            }
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Profit',
        color: 'rgba(248,161,63,1)',
        visible: true,
        data: [193.6, 128.8, 144.5],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueSuffix: ' M'
        },
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: 0.2,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var index = something.xAxis.categories.indexOf(this.x);
                if ((this.y > something.series[3].data[index]) || !something.series[3].visible) {
                    return this.y + '*';
                }
                return '';
            }
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Profit Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(186,60,61,.9)',
        visible: true,
        data: [123.6, 198.8, 208.5],
        tooltip: {
            valuePrefix: '$',
            valueSuffix: ' M'
        },
        pointPadding: 0.4,
        pointPlacement: 0.2,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var index = something.xAxis.categories.indexOf(this.x);
                if ((this.y > something.series[2].data[index]) || !something.series[2].visible) {
                    console.log(something.series.visible);
                    return this.y + '*';
                }
                return '';
            }
        }
    }]
};
    $('#container').highcharts(something);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7zc5peyf/4/